# Assign products to collection based on size

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I created a new collection template and I want to assign to it all products that have 'XL' size in their size variant.

I started from create and array of sizes for every product but now I'm stuck.

```
{% assign sizes = '' %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% if variant.available %}
{% assign sizes = sizes | append: variant.options[0] | append: '_' %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% assign sizesArr = sizes | split: '_' | uniq %}
```

What should I do next for showing only products that contains 'XL'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what do you mean by all products.

By default collection can show up to 50 products but you can overwrite this with a paginate object.

So if you have under 50 products you can just do this.

```
{%- for product in collection.products -%}
  {%- assign show_product = false -%}
  {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
    {%- for value in option.values -%}
      {%- assign value_handle = value | handle -%}
      {%- if value_handle == 'xl' -%}
        {%- assign show_product = true -%}
      {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
  {%- endfor -%}

  {%- if show_product -%}
    Add your product here
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

---

If you have more than 50 products you will need to wrap the above code in paginate object:

```
{% paginate collection.products by 9999 %}
  {%- for product in collection.products -%}
    {%- assign show_product = false -%}
    {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
      {%- for value in option.values -%}
        {%- assign value_handle = value | handle -%}
        {%- if value_handle == 'xl' -%}
          {%- assign show_product = true -%}
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endfor -%}

    {%- if show_product -%}
      Add your product here
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
{% endpaginate %}
```

But this request will take a toll on the server and slow down your site. So please consider this issue as well.

Comment: Thank you. We have thousands of products. There is a way to do that without load all products and check every one of them

Comment: No. The only way is to use tags if you rely only on liquid or to use the smart functionality of the collection and make a condition if the variant title contains "XL" in it or go overkill and use an app or some complex GraphQL request.

Comment: Whats the difference between checking for tags or checking for specific size? I'm not talking on the option to use smart collection.

Comment: Tags are integrated in the Shopify logic, so this is valid url `/collections/collection_handle/tag+tag+tag`, but there is no URL for variant options. So you are not checking for tags but you are using the TAG page to get all the products that have a specific tag. If you create a size tag for each product you can achieve this but it will take time to populate for each product.

Comment: So if I add 'XL' tag to every product I can use something like that? /collections/collection_handle/xl

Comment: Yes you can. And you will go directly to the page `/collections/collection_handle/xl` instead and the products will be filtered by default without doing any additional logic for filtration.